# images not storing in database with java

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to store images in the database using BLOB data type but when I call the class to insert it doesnt do as intended which is strange as it doesnt give me an error and I put an "out.println()" right after the method call to see if it goes in.

here is the code for inserting:

```
public void insertProfPic(int user_id, String file) {
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getCon();
        FileInputStream imageInputStream = null;

        PreparedStatement prep = null;
        try{
            String query = "INSERT INTO images(user_id, images) VALUES (?,?)";
            prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            File fil = new File(file);
            imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(fil);

            prep.setInt(1, user_id);
            prep.setBinaryStream(2, imageInputStream,(int)file.length());

            prep.execute();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally {
                        // close resources 

            if(imageInputStream!=null){
                            try {
                                imageInputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(imageUpload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my method call:

```
String clicked = request.getParameter("submit");
    imageUpload user = new imageUpload();
    out.println(clicked);

    String img = request.getParameter("picture");
    user.insertProfPic(id, img);
    out.println("file path: " + img);
```

Comment: `it doesnt do as intended` ... then what exactly is the problem?  Did a record get inserted, but the image data is off?  How have you determined that there is a problem here?

Comment: nothing got stored to the database at all, I ran queries in mySQL and it worked there but it doesnt store anything when I call it in Java

Comment: Your code doesn't commit. That's probably the problem.

Comment: how do I make this code "commit" then? I've been looking around the Internet and from what I've seen I more or less have the same code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit--

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode the images into a byte[] and store them as binary data